# Python: initialising many lists, good style of writing code

Tags: python, initialization, pep8

If I have in the `__init__` function of my class to initialise many lists to empty like this:

```
self.a = []
self.b = []
self.c = []
self.d = []
self.e = []
```

what is a better style of writing it - every list separately or maybe as

```
self.a,self.b,self.c,self.d,self.e = []*5
```

or maybe there is any other nice-looking way to do that?

Comment: are these local variables or instance variables? I'd expect you to be defining things like `self.a = []` in an `__init__` method.  You can do something like `a,b,c = [], [], []` to list them horizontally but it can get long with instance variables: `self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d, self.e = [],[],[],[],[]`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, of course the variables are the instance variables

Comment: I think you always go with what reads the best, and the "long" style (one on each line) is clearly it.

Comment: I agree with Jeff. Readability > # of lines

Answer (score 2):

```
a, b, c, d, e = ([] for _ in range(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I might use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
for ch in "abcde":   # or a list of strings
    setattr(self, ch, [])
```